# Methods like __<original_name>__ in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Are there methods that follow the pattern `__<original_name>__` and work as an alias, other than `__send__`?

Comment: how about `send` method like `object.send(:method_name, *parameters)`

Comment: I know that Gagan Gami. I only want to know about similar method names built-in in the language

Comment: You can see for yourself by `Object.instance_methods.grep /__\w+__/`.

Comment: Not built-in though, `elasticsearch-rails` provides a model method `__elasticsearch__`.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Alias of what?

Comment: @sawa alias for any other built-in method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to find a list of method names matching your pattern:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).flat_map(&:instance_methods).uniq.grep(/__\w+__/)
# => [:__send__, :__id__, :__method__, :__callee__, :__dir__]
```

Of these, [`Kernel#__method__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__), [`Kernel#__callee__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__), and [`Kernel#__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) aren't aliases, which leaves us with two:

- [`BasicObject#__send__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-__send__) is an alias for [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) (you already mentioned this)
- [`BasicObject#__id__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__) is an alias for [`Object#object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-object_id)

Comment: Note: it's almost always easier, faster, and more reliable to ask Ruby herself than to rely on strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Since we are at it I know the OP only asked about aliased methods but why not tag in some of the double underscored keywords `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__END__`, and `__ENCODING__`. The last of which is not aliased but is accessible through `Encoding.default_external`

Comment: or you can just open up pry and tab complete for them